# How to use the Snapchat Login Kit with an existing auth system?

Tags: javascript, snapchat

I'm creating my own social network and I've made an authentification server in JavaScript, with Json Web Tokens. Now, I want to integrate the Snapchat Login Kitto my app but it gives a token and it makes what I have made.
So that is my question : how can I use the Snapchat Login Kit to create a real account with my API and to allow the user to login with this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend server tools like firebase, Parse, Back4app, and many others that have the ability to create a user with multiple platforms with like Google, Facebook and many others. Personally, it might be best if you don't use snapchat because of the fact that a lot of people don't have snapchat and their credentials are hard to remember when you are not having to log into the app for a long time so the user might be asked to put in their password that they do not remember.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response. I have almost ended the APi, and I'd like to be the master of my code. So I think I'll keep it. But I've a last question : do you recommend me do use mongodb or mysql?